# How to avoid spacing in class name

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Currently, I am automating a web page using Watir-webdriver with page-objects. Here I want to check a class name if checkbox checked.  I need to check infra01 and checked  is  present if unchecked infra01 and unchecked exists or not.

```
<span class="infra01 infrastructure checked"></span>
<span class="infra01 digitinline unchecked"></span>
```

Please help how to proceed using regular expression.  Also please help me how to proceed the class name with spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the page object part, but you don't necessarily need to use a regular expression.  You can use the [`attribute_value`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/0.8.0/Watir/Element#attribute_value-instance_method) method to get the value of `class` attribute in the `span` tag and check to see if "unchecked" is included in the returned string:

```
browser.span.attribute_value("class").include? "unchecked"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to proceed with regexp:

```
browser.span(:class => /#{Regexp.escape("infra01 infrastructure checked")}/).when_present.click
```

If it possible to use "if" 1st element unchecked "else" click 2nd element